# UISlider with tick marks (colored like the track)

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to know the best way to do this:

[image: UISlider with ticks (colored)]

I have already done adding the marks as `UIViews`. Example:

```
let tick = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: (slider.frame.size.height - 10) / 2, width: 2, height: 10))
tick.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.7, alpha: 1)
tick.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
tick.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
tick.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
tick.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
tick.tag = i
slider.insertSubview(tick, belowSubview: slider)
```

In this case, 7 ticks have been added.
To control the color of these subviews. I used the tags, and in the value change of slider, with `if-else` statements, I´m changing the color to the `minimumTrackTintColor` or `maximumTrackTintColor` (green or grey). Example:

```
 if sender.value == 0 {
        slider.viewWithTag(1)?.backgroundColor = slider.maximumTrackTintColor
    }else if sender.value <= 5{
        slider.viewWithTag(1)?.backgroundColor = slider.minimumTrackTintColor
```

I don´t really like this way to do this... There is a better way?

Comment: Easier to use custom images for both tracks (on/off tracks).

Comment: How? Note that I have to change the marks when the value of slider is changing. If I use two images, what is the plan when I have to change mark to mark.

Comment: If the tick marks are dynamically changing, then subclassing UIControl is the only way (ie make ur own uislider).

Comment: Here is tutorial to get u started: https://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control

Comment: My code already works, but probably is not the best way. Thank you anyway GeneCode.

Comment: If you don't want to go deep into UIControl, another way i think of is just subclass the UISlider itself and override its drawRect and draw CG rects as the ticks. I think it would be simpler and better to manage.